# Popular TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 not listed in the Firefox ciphers

Tags: ssl, firefox, encryption, aes-gcm

Does anyone know why popular ciphers TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (frequntly used) not listed in the Firefox ciphers?

in about:config I expect to see something like:

security.ssl3.AES_128_GCM_SHA256 = true;
security.ssl3.AES_256_GCM_SHA384 = true.

Does this mean if I visit a website using one of these ciphers my connection stay unencrypted?

Comment: I see `security.ssl3.ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_gcm_sha256` and `security.ssl3.ecdhe_rsa_aes_128_gcm_sha256`, as well as versions with sha384. These make sense for TLS1.2 and below, TLS1.3 negotiates ciphersuites differently.

Comment: When I click on a LOCK sign, I see which cipher is in use right now, for example I am currently on my e-mail and it shows "connection encrypted with TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" and I can find a match for it,it will be security.ssl3.ecdhe_rsa_aes_256_gcm_sha384 but when I am on youtube it shows that connection encrypted with TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 but there is no match in firefox rules for this cipher

Comment: feels a bit uncomfortable when certain string missing ...

Comment: Your connection with youtube is TLS 1.3, but with this site it is TLS 1.2. As I said, TLS1.3 negotiates ciphersuites differently so those ciohersuite strings that are valid for TLS1.2 and below are *obsolete* in TLS1.3.

Comment: Just wondering what gonna happen if I add missing strings manually ?

Comment: or what if my TLS1.3 hello will be downgraded for some reason.. does this mean there will be no encryption even with TLS1.2 because firefox has no string for TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 ???

Comment: No, that will not happen. First of all, the protocol version is negotiated *before* any ciphersuites are negotiated. Second of all, both the server *and* the client have to successfully complete the handshake before any data is even sent over the network. It's impossible to send unencrypted data over a TLS connection unless a truly spectacular bug is present.

Comment: I was hoping someone who is more of an expert on Firefox TLS configuration settings would see this question and provide you with some answers. I'm sorry that didn't happen. The question is actually off-topic here. It should've been asked on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) which is a part of the same family as this website. I can't promise you'll get better results there but I think it's worth a try. If you do decide to post there please delete this question here.

Comment: No. I think I am done with this. Thank you for your time and answers. BR